# Two Radio buttons with different messages when checked

Tags: c#, radio-button, messagebox

I need use two radio buttons; one is ON and another is OFF.

When we click on any radio button, the application shows me both messages! How do I make it show only the message for the radio button clicked?

```
    private void rB_OFF_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked OFF");
    }

    private void rB_ON_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked ON");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because, either the `radioButton` turns `true` or `false`, it just trigger the `checkedChanged` event, so you need to do this.

```
private void rB_OFF_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
      if (rB_OFF.Checked == true)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked OFF");
      }
    }

    private void rB_ON_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
      if (rB_ON.Checked == true)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked ON");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`CheckChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event

> Occurs when the value of the Checked property changes.

This means that the radio button either went from checked -> not checked, or vice-versa.  In your handler, you need to check to see if the `sender` is [`Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx) or not.

```
private void rB_ON_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var rb = (RadioButton)sender;

    if (rb.Checked) {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked ON");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is because the radioButton is boolean ok? In the same scope, only one can checked; how can I create a condition so that only the button clicked to display the message? Thank you, Ocaccy.

Comment: No, it is a `RadioButton`. It has a `bool Checked` property.

Comment: Thank you; now when I start the app, shows me the message of the radiobutton default. How to not show the message when start the app?

Comment: @OcaccyPontes attach the handler after the `InitializeComponent` method in the Constructor.

Comment: Mark Hall, how to do this? Thank you, ocaccy.

Comment: @OcaccyPontes Do not use the designer to attach your Handler. If you look at simplecoder's answer the first part is how you would add the EventHandler to the event, If you look at your form you will see a Method that has an `InitializeComponent` statement in it. put the code assigning the eventhandler to the event after that.

Comment: [code]         public Form1()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            // what put in here? }                          
[/code]                                                                Thank you,

Comment: @OcaccyPontes  `rB_OFF.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rB_OFF_CheckedChanged);`
`rB_ON.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rB_ON_CheckedChanged);`

Comment: Thank you, Mark Hall and all friends who helped me.

Answer (score 2):

it's good to have in general one event for all radio buttons 
Same event for all the radio buttons

more details here  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx)

```
 this.radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
    this.radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);


    void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;

        if (rb == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sender is not a RadioButton");
            return;
        }

        // Ensure that the RadioButton.Checked property 
        // changed to true. 
        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            // Keep track of the selected RadioButton by saving a reference 
            // to it.
            selectedrb = rb;
            MessageBox.Show(selectedrb.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you check one, the other gets unchecked and you have event handler on `CheckedChanged`. So check changes and event is fired on both controls.

Instead Get additional information from `object sender`. `Sender` will be the RadioButton on which this event was fired. Cast it into RadioButton and use its `Checked` property.

```
    private void rB_OFF_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;

        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked OFF");
        }            
    }

    private void rB_ON_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;

        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked ON");
        }            
    }
```